# silverlight 3: Any free database available for silverlight(stored in isolated storage)?

Tags: silverlight

Any free database available for silverlight that can be stored in isolated storage?

Comment: I know we can use XML but that should be my last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this approach which uses XML/Linq:
http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/10/Silverlight-Client-Side-Database-via-LINQ-and-Isolated-Storage.aspx

Answer (score 3):

There is this POC of SQLite in isolated storage, but I don't know the current status:
http://www.itwriting.com/blog/1695-proof-of-concept-c-sqlite-running-in-silverlight.html

Answer (score 1):

The Perst database from McObject is an option. It is dual license -- if you use it in an open source application, there is no licensing charge.

The source code is available for free download from McObject's Web site.

McObject has posted a demo of Perst running in a Silverlight application on its Web site; you can download the demo source code, too. The demo page is at

http://www.mcobject.com/silverlight-demo

Answer (score 1):

Are you considering an OODB? It can simplify your persistence.

I recommend you to try [db4o](http://www.db4o.com) (which supports Silverlight 3) and report any issue you may find.

Best

Adriano

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to load and save a complete object graph (and maintain references between objects) you could look at CSLA Light to binary serialize them.

http://www.dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Binary-Serialisation-In-Silverlight.aspx